# Can a URL be rewritten to a subdomain without changing the URL in address bar?

Tags: .htaccess, cookies

**Background**

1) I have a php upload script located at http://www.example.com/up/upload.php

2) I have a subdomain cdn1.example.com that is a mirror of www.example.com

3) I want all requests made to http://www.example.com/up/upload.php to redirect to http://cdn1.example.com/up/upload.php

**The Problem**

My upload.php script relies on cookies to work properly

I can successfully forward all requests made to www. to cdn1. but the URL in the addressbar changes.  As a result the cookies are lost because its a different domain.   Setting my cookies to the root example.com domain is not an option unfortunately.

**The Question**

Is it possible in my scenario to have upload.php be served from my cdn1. subdomain but have the users browser think its still coming from www. so that all the cookies are still used?   If this is possible is there an example I could try plugging into my server?

Comment: Only thing I can think is to have your `www.` script send a [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) to your `cdn1.` script, get the response from `curl` and deliver it from `www`.

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is doable. The browser opens a request to `www.` and if that request is opened to a different url `cdn1.`, then it would have to update the address bar. I've never heard of the browser having a request open to a different server than that which is displayed to the user. Unless you used javascript to go to `cdn1.`, but that's still not doing what you want & would have the cookie problem